# Why can't I print all method of a string variable in GDB?

Tags: c++, gdb

I have a snippet like this:

```
string a = "abc";
```

When I use "ptype" to inspect this varable:

```
ptype a
```

I found gdb simply returns

```
type = std::string
```

Though I expect it returns a full list of fields and methods. Use `ptype\r a` can return more results though the extra information there seems to be internal implementations. Does anyone have an easy way to check all public method of an object in GDB?
[image]

Comment: Does `ptype /M a` (uppercase M) show any methods?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick No, it shows `(gdb) pt /M a
type = std::string`

Comment: I just tried `ptype` and it works for me. Can you show a bit more of your code ?

Comment: Maybe we can reproduce this. What OS are you running, and what are the versions of gdb and the c++ compiler?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks so much for your help! Uploaded a picture at https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvqTR.png I'm using GCC 6.3.0, CMake 3.15.3 and GDB 8.3 bundled with IDE under Windows 10

Comment: @calvinBroadus Added a screenshot in the post. Thanks!

Comment: Here is the result of `ptype /r a`: https://justpaste.it/1plav

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the mingw compiler. Maybe someone who has it can help.